# How to kill 2 child processes in a given order

Tags: c, linux, fork, wait, child-process

I want to terminate child processes in a given order, but my program sometimes output the correct result, sometimes no.

Can anybody please what I'm doing wrong

***The Correct Order:***
1st C-process has terminated.
2nd C-process has terminated.
P-process has terminated.

***Getting this output sometimes:***
2nd C-process has terminated.
1st C-process has terminated.
P-process has terminated.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t child_pid = -1 ; //Global
pid_t child_pidb = -1 ; //Global

void kill_child(int sig) {

    kill(child_pid,SIGKILL);
}

void kill_childb(int sig){

    kill(child_pidb,SIGKILL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pid_t child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid > 0) {
        
        pid_t child_pidb = fork();
        
        if(child_pidb>0) { 
            signal(SIGSTKFLT,(void (*)(int))kill_child);
            sleep(3);
            signal(SIGCHLD,(void (*)(int))kill_childb);
            wait(NULL);
             printf("P-process has terminated.");
             exit(0);
        }
        else if (child_pidb ==0 ) {
            printf("2nd C-process has terminated.");
        }
    }
    else if (child_pid == 0){
        printf("1st C-process has terminated.");
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee about the execution order of your processes if you don't implement your own mechanism to control the order of process execution or termination. Please explain the purpose of the signal handlers in your code. Don't answer in comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Why don't you kill the first process (which, as you discovered, is a somewhat misleading term since you only send a signal to it which will cause it to terminate, sometime, in the future) and then [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) for it to terminate before you kill the second one? `wait`may return `ECHILD` if the child has terminated before the wait is executed, which is also a possibility.

Comment: You are creating a zombie process. You are doing a _single_ `wait` call. You need to do two of them.

Comment: I don't understand why you are bothering with signals at all.  Since you want the parent to finish last, and the first child that is spawned to finish first, you can implement it simply by waiting for the first child to finish before you fork the second.  And then wait for the 2nd.  Is there a requirement that all 3 be running at the same time? (ie, do you need to fork the 2nd before the first is complete?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read *carefully* both [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html). And of course [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Consider having simpler signal handlers, each would just set some global variable declared as `volatile sigatomic_t gotsig;`

Then code some [finite state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) around [sigpause(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigpause.3.html) and/or [waitpid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

Another possibility might be to use [signalfd(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) with some event loop around [poll(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

The important thing is to draw on paper your finite automaton graph and to think in terms of a [transition system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_system). You might view your signals (and other events like a process ending) as input to some [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) algorithm, probably an [LL parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser).

Study for inspiration the code of some [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) shell, e.g. [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell), and use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand its behavior in terms of [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

BTW, you forgot to handle an important case: a [fork(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) can fail. See [errno(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) and [perror(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

Remember that several milliseconds (or more, on a very loaded Linux system - see [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) could happen between a process being terminated, and the corresponding `waitpid` to succeed. And with [multi-core processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor)s, you could have two different processes running on two different cores.

Read [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

Comment: All you say is right in the general sense but I don't see a signal handler here and I don't think one is necessary. What is it that you have in mind?

Comment: OP is asking for having signal handlers. I don't exactly understand what OP have in mind